# Add Data to firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I have a database with which I put the photo in the link. I would like to add 'PostTig' and 'PostesMig in the right places.
Except I don't know how hooks work. I looked at the doc but I did not find a concrete example with a firebase database. I think my code is completely wrong.

My code:

```
export default function AddProduct(props) {

    const [DesignationAS400, setDesignationAS400] = useState('');
    const [CodeCommun, setCodeCommun] = useState('');
    const [RefFournisseur, setRefFournisseur] = useState('');
    const [SelectedPoste, setSelectedPoste] = useState("PostesMig");
    
    if(selectedPoste == 'PostesMig') {
        
       const addPoste =  (poste) => {
           
            firebase.database()
            .ref('PostesMig')
            .push({
                DesignationAS400: setDesignationAS400.useState,
                CodeCommun:setCode.useState,
                RefFournisseur: setRefFournisseur.useState,
            });
        }
    } else if(selectedPoste == 'PostesTig') {
      const  addPoste =  (poste) => {
            firebase.database()
            .ref('PostesTig')
            .push({
                DesignationAS400: setDesignationAS400.useState,
                CodeCommun:setCodeCommun.useState,
                RefFournisseur: setRefFournisseur.useState,
            });          
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Ajouter un produit</Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput 
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
            value={DesignationAS400}
            placeholder='Designation AS 400'
            
            />
            <TextInput 
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={text => setCode(text)}
            value={CodeCommun}
            placeholder='Code Commun'
                       
            />
            <TextInput 
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={text => setRefFourn(text)}
            value={RefFournisseur}
            placeholder='Ref Fournisseur'
            
            />
            <Picker 
                style={styles.picker}
                selectedValue={selectedPoste}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedPoste(itemValue)}
            >
                <Picker.Item label="Postes MIG" value="PostesMig" />
                <Picker.Item label="Postes TIG" value="PostesTig" />
                
            </Picker>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button
                onPress={add}
                title="Ajouter"
                />
            </View>
        </View>);}
```

[image: Json Firebase]

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? When you run it in a debugger and step through it, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: it tells me cant 'find variable: selectedPoste but I don't understand why. I think I'm having trouble handling hooks

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. You declare the hook at `const [SelectedPoste, setSelectedPoste] = useState("PostesMig");`, so `SelectedPoste` with an uppercase `S`. But then you try to use it as `if(selectedPoste == 'PostesTig')`, so `selectedPoste` with a lowercase `s`. You'll need to make sure the case matches between where you declare the variable and where you use it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, indeed sorry. It is a lack of attention. By cons I do not know what to spend in the button onPress